# SSIS Script Component error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, ssis

Getting the following error when trying to run a script in SSIS
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

at ScriptMain.PreExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PreExecute()

The script was working fine in the past. I recently changed the metadata and data of the input (the input by itself is working), so that might be what is causing the issue. I dont know exactly what could be wrong however.

here's my script

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
```

{

```
private Dictionary<string, string> tsgMapping;

private Dictionary<string, string> fgMapping;
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    //load mapping
    tsgMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    fgMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var mappingFilePath = Connections.Connection.ConnectionString;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(mappingFilePath))
    {
        reader.ReadLine(); //skip first line of headers
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var splitLine = line.Split('|');

            tsgMapping.Add(splitLine[0], splitLine[1]);
            fgMapping.Add(splitLine[0], splitLine[2]);
        }
    }
}


public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    /*
     * Add your code here
     */
}


public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (!tsgMapping.TryGetValue(Row.TransactionName, out var tsg))
    {
        tsg = "Ask CPB";
    }

    Row.TSGRaw = tsg;

    if (!fgMapping.TryGetValue(Row.TransactionName, out var fg))
    {
        fg = "Ask CPB";
    }

    Row.FGRaw = fg;

}
```

}

Comment: Put a check on the size of the `tsgMapping` and `fgMapping` arrays.  Most likely, one of the lines you are splitting doesn't have enough `|`s

Answer (score 0):

After reading my own post I figured out what was wrong.
There was bad data on my mapping file (blank row at the end) which was causing the script to fail.